# building a meteor-ionic mobile app using ionic CLI

Tags: android, meteor, ionic-framework

I'm working on a mobile app using ionic framework with meteor as server.
I tried building the app for android using ionic CLI (`ionic build android`)

But when I connected my phone to my Laptop (with meteor running), the app wasn't linked to the server.

My question is: is it possible to build the app using ionic CLI and then link it somehow to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't no with meteor server but the command for ionic live in android

```
ionic cordova run android --device -l
```